# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in UrlsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code:

```
class UrlsController < ApplicationController
def new
 @shortened_url = Url.new
end
def create
 @shortened_url = Url.new(params[:url])
 if @shortened_url.save
   flash[:shortened_id] = @shortened_url.id
   redirect_to new_url_url
 else
   render :action => "new"
  end
end

def show
     @shortened_url = Url.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to @shortened_url.url
     end

 end
```

I'm getting the error I know is related to the required parameters and permit. Any one can tell me how the method need to be written?

this is the model:

```
class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :url, :presence => true
end
```

the error is when submitting the form. I get 
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in UrlsController#create

Comment: That's all I have in the controller  what other details should I provide?

Answer (score 0):

It needed the use of strong parameters

```
class UrlsController < ApplicationController
def new
 @shortened_url = Url.new
 end
def create
 @shortened_url = Url.new(shortened_url)
 if @shortened_url.save
   flash[:shortened_id] = @shortened_url.id
   redirect_to new_url_url
 else
   render :action => "new"
 end
end

 def show
 @shortened_url = Url.find(params[:id])
 redirect_to @shortened_url.url
end

private

 def shortened_url
   params.require(:url).permit!
 end

end
```